# "Dynamically" executing code in Java

Tags: java, sockets, dynamic

I'm looking to execute predefined Java code (hence the quotation marks) when a certain message arrives from a socket. What is the best way of doing this? I thought about parsing the message and then running some sort of case check but I thought there might be a neater way of doing the same.

Comment: depends on usecase, are you expecting code as input ? are you expecting some flags based on which you can take decision which implementation to execute (you could use polymorphism or runtime binding here)

Comment: I'm expecting flags, sort of "if message was 'a', then do this; if message was 'b', do some other thing; else, don't do anything".

Comment: `if (message.contains("a")) doSomethingA(); else if (message.contains("B")) doSomethingB() ...`?

Comment: create an interface with multiple implementation for your cases, and use a Builder method to create (or just retrieve) implementation after parsing flag, and to get implementation use `HashMap<String, SomeInterface>` instead of using if-else or switch case

Comment: So, you're looking for an `if` statement, or maybe a `switch` statement??

Comment: I would use a map, whose keys are the messages, and whose values are implementations of the interface that declares the method to be called.

Comment: @Laura how many posibilities do you have? if you have only three, use a `if/elseif/else`, if the number of posibilities will grow up, then use a Builder.

Comment: Based on the input you receive (if the messages are limited to a certain set) I'd go for a [command pattern approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) where you add each command with the string that should trigger the command to a map (key the string, value the command-object) and then just execute a `commandMap.get(inputString).run()` statement similar to what @DavidWallace has recommended

Comment: Ain't all Java code dynamically executed? :-)

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a look at RMI.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! Hadn't thought about maps, it looks like an awesome approach.

Comment: Sure.  Comment again if you think you'll need help with the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a lot of ways. As people said, you can implement using a lot of desing patterns like Builder.

But here is a simple way to implement your client:

```
public class DateClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serverAddress = "ipAdress";
        Socket s = new Socket(serverAddress, 9090); // use the right port
        BufferedReader input
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        char answer = input.readLine().charAt(0);
        switch (answer) {
            case 'a':
                //do something for a
                break;
            case 'b':
                //do something for b
                break;
            case 'c':
                //do something for c
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No valid entry");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It needs verification while reading the package from server, or it may throw exceptions.

Comment: ... and it relies on every possible message having a different first character, so it doesn't extend well to the general case.

Comment: Yeah, true. Just did this way to attend what she sayd: "I'm expecting flags, sort of "if message was 'a', then do this; if message was 'b', do some other thing; else, don't do anything". ". But it could be much better :D

Answer (score 1):

Its not really "dynamically".  You mean to execute a command on a given request from the socket?

**Rule #1 of building services: Sanitize all input.**

For this reason I would avoid any kind of methodology that uses Reflection to obtain method names and execute them that way.

Essentially you are looking for a bit of logic to determine what to do with the input request.

This could be done a number of ways.

1. Using a switch case on a String name.
2. Using a HashMap to map the String name to a generic interface (void run( Object input ))
3. Using an event dispatcher mechanism to alert listeners of input request.

How you decide to implement this is up to you and really depends on your goals.

What you determine to be a "message" from the socket involves formatting.  I am assuming that you are formatting the data so the receiver knows a message of X bytes is coming so it can be buffered and processed only when the entire message has been received.

Formatting of data on the socket is beyond the scope of this question.  There are lot of resources for designing and building RPC services.  May google be with you.